# Unable to use multiple functions in single native C++ library file in Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android application that is using C++ native library. I have integrated the c++ into my project and call the C++ function from Java through JNI successfully. But the problem is I cannot declare multiple functions in single C++ native library.

This is my native C++ code in native-lib.cpp file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT
jstring
Java_media_memento_memento_SphereCameraActivity_stitchPhotos(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject ) {

    std::string hello = "This is the function one";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}



}
```

From the Java, I load the library like this

```
static {
      System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
   }
```

and call the function. It was working. But I trued to add the new function to the native-lib.cpp as follow.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT
jstring
Java_media_memento_memento_SphereCameraActivity_stitchPhotos(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject ) {

    std::string hello = "This is the function one";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

    JNIEXPORT
jstring
Java_media_memento_memento_SphereCameraActivity_sayHello(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject ) {
    std::string hello = "Stitching the photo in C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

}
```

As you can see, the new function is sayHello. When I run my application and call sayHello function from java, the app crashes.

The error in the logcat seems not related to the problem at all.

[image]

How can I solve the problem and use multiple functions in a single native c++ library file?

Comment: Does the app crash if you only add the new native method to your Java and C++ files, but don't call it?

Comment: No.The app only crashes when I call that funcion.

Comment: What if you only call the second function, not the first one? What if you remove the declaration of the first method?

Comment: I don't suppose there's any more info in the log if you set the error level to warning or debug?

Answer (score 1):

I tried by doing this way and it's working:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_package_name_Keys_apiKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject object)
{
    std::string api_key = "https://api.api.net";
    return env->NewStringUTF(api_key.c_str());
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_package_name_Keys_imageApiKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject object)
{
    std::string image_api_key = "https://api.api.com/";
    return env->NewStringUTF(image_api_key.c_str());
}
```